# Avoiding sunlight in school assembly area

Tags: temperature, comfort, summer

This is my school's assembly area :

[image]

The place is generally used for the assembly and various other things. But the problem is that it receives a lot of sunlight and it is difficult to use it during the later part of the day.

So, I would like something like a roof, which doesn't entirely block out sunlight but makes the place a little more comfortable.

One thing I have thought of is installing small nets or rods and then growing creepers on it which would act as a roof. But I am unsure whether this is practical.

P.S. I am new to lifehacks.SE and so am not sure whether this question rightly belongs to the site or not. So, please mention in the comments if it is off-topic.

All kinds of solutions are welcome but it would be great if the solution is eco-friendly. Thanks.

Comment: Your idea of a trellis (rods, or cables to buildings holding up netting for plants) seems appealing.It might need guy wires to prevent collapsing, especially when windy. In any case, it would need to be arranged so as not to obstruct use of the courtyard or pose a hazard. Best wishes for improving the area!

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik Thanks. But with the way creepers entwine, it's highely unlikely that they would fall.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'm wondering what you'd be planting these climbers or creepers in - they'd need to be in the ground to make any size, pots will restrict them too much. Also, your idea of nets or rods for climbers won't work - the weight of the climbers will pull down the support system, probably on top of everyone's heads. You can build a solid wood **pergola** and then add climbers, but if the ground there is solid paved or concreted, you'd need to make holes in it for the foot of the pergola and also to be able to plant climbers. If you have to make holes in it anyway, why not plant a few trees for natural shade.

Otherwise, some sort of large awning suspended across from the top building to the other.

UPDATED ANSWER; You've said you'd be planting creepers in large pots on the first floor and having ropes strung across for them to cling to. The trouble with plants is, they always want to grow upwards, not sideways. This means they need tying in or persuading to grow along something, and that won't be possible suspended in air. You may get a branch to go along a rope, but the distance you want to cover will be unachievable (if your picture is of the actual area) because the plant will be restricted in its growth by the pot, even if its a large pot. Lastly, as I said before, weight will be an issue - let's suppose you had open soil on your second floor, and it was deep, meaning there's plenty of root room for a creeper, the weight as it grew would make it a danger to anyone below because it is only held up by some rope or mesh.

Comment: What if we use small nets instead of a huge net.?

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest moving this question to the G & L section (which is where I'm primarily from). More to the point, where would you be growing these climbers, I mean, what in... the amount of root room dictates how large a plant can get, ergo, the weight once its full grown. If it doesn't grow properly because it doesn't have enough root room, it won't provide shade anyway.

Comment: There are columns on the building.  One could attach ropes on the columns and creepers would be grown in larger than normal pots. It doesn't have to be very dense I guess. We can leave some space for sunlight to slip through. By the way, what is the G and L section?

Comment: Garden and Landscape. Even large pots won't enable plants to get big enough to grow up and then go  horizontally to give some shade, I'm afraid.

Comment: Up and horizontal? The creepers will be grown from the first floor.

Comment: Well, if you want to try it, go ahead...

Comment: I do not wish to try it without confirming whether it would work or not

Comment: See updated answer...

Comment: Please have a look at the image titled "Pergola covered in bouganvillea" on [this](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pergola) page. I think that type of structure would be better suited.

Comment: Yep, that's what I mentioned originally in my answer.

Comment: Wouldn't that kind of structure require a lot of pillars?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23543/discussion-between-bamboo-and-yashbhatt).

Answer (score 2):

The Romans used to string ropes across arenas and attach sails to them to provide shade. You could do something like that. 
If you are in a maritime area maybe you could get old sails cheap?